# DropdownList asp web forms control

Tags: webforms

I wanted to know what is the best way to provide a dropdown list of row columns from a database into the dropdown list web form control.  I started on the Page_Load function and want the list data to be available when the page loads for the dropdown on my aspx page. In the scenario, my dropdown Id is DropDownList1.  How can I add to this current code?

```
SqlConnection myConnection = ConfigManager.GetConnection(ConnectionTarget.TestModule);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [col1]"
      + ",[col2]"
      + ",[col3]"
      + ",[col4]"
      + "FROM[db].[dbo].[table]"
      + "ORDER BY col1", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myAdapter.Fill(ds);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a list. Add the rows or values from the database to the list and bind the list to the dropdownlist.

```
List<string> dbList = new List<string>();
```

After defining the list, fill it up with the values from your database. You can then bind it to the dropdownlist as follows:

```
dropdownlistId.DataSource = dbList; 
dropdownlistId.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing I realized that the error was syntactical and I was missing spaces between commands in the sql query select for the list.  Once I fixed the syntax and spacing, the list populated in the control.  Thank you for the advice.